# TcmServiceHost.exe goes down

Tags: 2011, core-service

As soon as I do publishing, but only happens intermittently, I see this error in Tridion CME:

> Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/2011/netTcp. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0436131. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2660.
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2660

Tridion content manager service host service goes down in Tridion Content Manager server. As soon as we restart this service everything will work.

In event viewer under application logs we see this as error:

> The run-time environment has detected an inconsistency in its internal state. This indicates a potential instability in the process that could be caused by the custom components running in the COM+ application, the components they make use of, or other factors. 
>   CTransactionMarshal::MarshalInterface
>   Process Name: TcmServiceHost.exe
>   The serious nature of this error has caused the process to terminate.
>   Error Code = 0x80030009 : Invalid pointer error.
>   COM+ Services Internals Information:
>   File: d:\w7rtm\com\complus\src\comsvcs\txprop\txmar.cpp, Line: 213 Comsvcs.dll file version: ENU 2001.12.8530.16385 shp

We could not find out any other information in event viewer or in Tridion Logs (with log level in debug mode).

Maybe the underlying cause of the problem is related with Tridion Events or Custom Resolver. The issue seems to happen when publish transaction is created, but in any case I need more information.

### Question:

Anyone knows how I could enable debug mode in TcmServiceHost.exe.config?

Comment: To turn on WCF logging in [TridionHome]\bin\TcmServiceHost.exe.config:
· Stop the Tridion CM Service Host Service
· Look for and uncomment the section starting <!-- Uncomment sources below to enabled WCF tracing -->
· Ensure that the directory exists in the element for sharedListeners/add/@initializeData
· In the TcmServiceHost properties add "-debug" in start parameters textbox.
· Start the service.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exact same issue while preview or publish a specific page.

Just check/review the code of the TBB you have written specifically the DWT (if you are using it) and figure out if there is any syntax error in it.

In my case this error was coming due to a syntax error and correcting it resolved the issue.

On the same note, you may check whatever code you have written.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have inspected all our DWT TBBs without finding anything. In fact, yesterday, I have not been able to reproduce the problem again. I am still researching.